# Installing AMD Drivers on CentOS 7 - X Server Error

Tags: centos, drivers, x-server, amd-graphics

I have been trying to install the AMD drivers on my CentOS computer for about a month now with no luck. I have followed [the AMD guide](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/How-To-Install-Uninstall-AMDGPU-PRO-driver-on-a-CentOS-Based-System.aspx); however, I get an error saying,

```
Error: Package: glamor-amdgpu-1.19.0-511655.el6.x86_64 (amdgpu-pro-local)
       Requires: xserver-abi(videodrv-19) >= 0
```

I have been working with AMD support this entire time and they don't seem eager to solve my problem in a timely manner.

I have checked that I have xserver and it is up to date and running.

What steps should I take to resolve this problem?

Result of running sudo bash -x amdgpu-pro-preinstall.sh

```
    +++ id -u
++ [[ 0 -ne 0 ]]
++ :
+ SUDO=
+ checkonly=false
+ err=false
+ os_release
+ [[ -r /etc/os-release ]]
+ . /etc/os-release
++ NAME='CentOS Linux'
++ VERSION='7 (Core)'
++ ID=centos
++ ID_LIKE='rhel fedora'
++ VERSION_ID=7
++ PRETTY_NAME='CentOS Linux 7 (Core)'
++ ANSI_COLOR='0;31'
++ CPE_NAME=cpe:/o:centos:centos:7
++ HOME_URL=https://www.centos.org/
++ BUG_REPORT_URL=https://bugs.centos.org/
++ CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT=CentOS-7
++ CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION=7
++ REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT=centos
++ REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION=7
+ case "$ID" in
+ name=RHEL
+ extra='Extra Packages for Linux (EPEL) Repository'
+ (( 0 ))
+ set --
+ false
+ cat
The amdgpu-pro driver requires access to specific RPMs from centos installation 
media as well as access to Extra Packages for Linux (EPEL) Repository

This script will confirm that all required prerequisite files and repositories
are available in order to successfully install the amdgpu-pro driver.  
Press ENTER to continue . . ."
+ read

+ install_extrapkgs_RHEL
+ rpm --quiet -q epel-release
++ uname -r
+ local kernel_ver=3.10.0-693.11.1.el7.x86_64
+ yum list all kernel-devel-3.10.0-693.11.1.el7.x86_64
+ '[' 0 -gt 0 ']'
+ install_from_media_RHEL
+ '[' centos '!=' rhel ']'
+ return
+ false
+ echo 'Checking if repositories were set up successfully...'
Checking if repositories were set up successfully...
+ check_repo_RHEL
++ yum repolist
+ local 'repolist=Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirror.lstn.net
 * epel: mirror.rnet.missouri.edu
 * extras: centos.mirror.lstn.net
 * nux-dextop: li.nux.ro
 * rpmfusion-free-updates: mirrors.lug.mtu.edu
 * ulyaoth: repos.ulyaoth.io
 * updates: centos.mirror.lstn.net
repo id                        repo name                                  status
!adobe-linux-x86_64            Adobe Systems Incorporated                      3
!amdgpu-pro-local              AMD amdgpu Pro local repository                60
!base/7/x86_64                 CentOS-7 - Base                             9,591
!epel/x86_64                   Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x8 12,184
!extras/7/x86_64               CentOS-7 - Extras                             327
!forensics/7/x86_64            CERT Forensics Tools Repository             1,439
!forensics-splunk/7/x86_64     CERT Forensics Tools Repository - Splunk        3
!nux-dextop/x86_64             Nux.Ro RPMs for general desktop use         2,570
!rpmfusion-free-updates/x86_64 RPM Fusion for EL 7 - Free - Updates          223
!ulyaoth/7/x86_64              Ulyaoth Repository                          1,312
!updates/7/x86_64              CentOS-7 - Updates                          1,573
!vivaldi                       vivaldi                                        15
repolist: 29,300'
++ awk '// && ! /centos-install-media/'
++ echo Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile amdgpu-pro-17.30-458935 amdgpu-pro-17.30-458935.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261 amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.40-501128.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.50-511655 amdgpu-pro-17.50-511655.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-preinstall.sh cert-forensics-tools-release-el7.rpm eclipse-java-photon-M4-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz expat-2.1.0-10.el7_3.i686.rpm fluxgui 'IBM US Relocation Questionaire _TAC.doc' lib64udev0-182-5-mdv2012.0.x86_64.rpm libdrm-2.4.74-1.el7.i686.rpm libpciaccess-0.13.4-3.el7_3.i686.rpm libselinux-2.5-11.el7.i686.rpm libsepol-2.5-6.el7.x86_64.rpm libudev-147-2.73.el6_8.2.x86_64.rpm mesa-libGL-17.0.1-6.20170307.el7.i686.rpm mesa-libglapi-17.0.1-6.20170307.el7.i686.rpm 'vivaldi-stable-1.12.955.48-1.x86_64(1).rpm' vivaldi-stable-1.12.955.48-1.x86_64.rpm xflux xflux64.tgz xorg-x11-server-1.17.2-22.el7.src.rpm xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.17.4-16.el6.centos.i686.rpm xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.19.3-11.el7.x86_64.rpm base: centos.mirror.lstn.net amdgpu-pro-17.30-458935 amdgpu-pro-17.30-458935.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261 amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.40-501128.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.50-511655 amdgpu-pro-17.50-511655.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-preinstall.sh cert-forensics-tools-release-el7.rpm eclipse-java-photon-M4-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz expat-2.1.0-10.el7_3.i686.rpm fluxgui 'IBM US Relocation Questionaire _TAC.doc' lib64udev0-182-5-mdv2012.0.x86_64.rpm libdrm-2.4.74-1.el7.i686.rpm libpciaccess-0.13.4-3.el7_3.i686.rpm libselinux-2.5-11.el7.i686.rpm libsepol-2.5-6.el7.x86_64.rpm libudev-147-2.73.el6_8.2.x86_64.rpm mesa-libGL-17.0.1-6.20170307.el7.i686.rpm mesa-libglapi-17.0.1-6.20170307.el7.i686.rpm 'vivaldi-stable-1.12.955.48-1.x86_64(1).rpm' vivaldi-stable-1.12.955.48-1.x86_64.rpm xflux xflux64.tgz xorg-x11-server-1.17.2-22.el7.src.rpm xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.17.4-16.el6.centos.i686.rpm xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.19.3-11.el7.x86_64.rpm epel: mirror.rnet.missouri.edu amdgpu-pro-17.30-458935 amdgpu-pro-17.30-458935.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261 amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.40-501128.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.50-511655 amdgpu-pro-17.50-511655.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-preinstall.sh cert-forensics-tools-release-el7.rpm eclipse-java-photon-M4-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz expat-2.1.0-10.el7_3.i686.rpm fluxgui 'IBM US Relocation Questionaire _TAC.doc' lib64udev0-182-5-mdv2012.0.x86_64.rpm libdrm-2.4.74-1.el7.i686.rpm libpciaccess-0.13.4-3.el7_3.i686.rpm libselinux-2.5-11.el7.i686.rpm libsepol-2.5-6.el7.x86_64.rpm libudev-147-2.73.el6_8.2.x86_64.rpm mesa-libGL-17.0.1-6.20170307.el7.i686.rpm mesa-libglapi-17.0.1-6.20170307.el7.i686.rpm 'vivaldi-stable-1.12.955.48-1.x86_64(1).rpm' vivaldi-stable-1.12.955.48-1.x86_64.rpm xflux xflux64.tgz xorg-x11-server-1.17.2-22.el7.src.rpm xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.17.4-16.el6.centos.i686.rpm xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.19.3-11.el7.x86_64.rpm extras: centos.mirror.lstn.net amdgpu-pro-17.30-458935 amdgpu-pro-17.30-458935.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261 amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.40-501128.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.50-511655 amdgpu-pro-17.50-511655.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-preinstall.sh cert-forensics-tools-release-el7.rpm eclipse-java-photon-M4-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz expat-2.1.0-10.el7_3.i686.rpm fluxgui 'IBM US Relocation Questionaire _TAC.doc' lib64udev0-182-5-mdv2012.0.x86_64.rpm libdrm-2.4.74-1.el7.i686.rpm libpciaccess-0.13.4-3.el7_3.i686.rpm libselinux-2.5-11.el7.i686.rpm libsepol-2.5-6.el7.x86_64.rpm libudev-147-2.73.el6_8.2.x86_64.rpm mesa-libGL-17.0.1-6.20170307.el7.i686.rpm mesa-libglapi-17.0.1-6.20170307.el7.i686.rpm 'vivaldi-stable-1.12.955.48-1.x86_64(1).rpm' vivaldi-stable-1.12.955.48-1.x86_64.rpm xflux xflux64.tgz xorg-x11-server-1.17.2-22.el7.src.rpm xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.17.4-16.el6.centos.i686.rpm xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.19.3-11.el7.x86_64.rpm nux-dextop: li.nux.ro amdgpu-pro-17.30-458935 amdgpu-pro-17.30-458935.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261 amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.40-501128.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.50-511655 amdgpu-pro-17.50-511655.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-preinstall.sh cert-forensics-tools-release-el7.rpm eclipse-java-photon-M4-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz expat-2.1.0-10.el7_3.i686.rpm fluxgui 'IBM US Relocation Questionaire _TAC.doc' lib64udev0-182-5-mdv2012.0.x86_64.rpm libdrm-2.4.74-1.el7.i686.rpm libpciaccess-0.13.4-3.el7_3.i686.rpm libselinux-2.5-11.el7.i686.rpm libsepol-2.5-6.el7.x86_64.rpm libudev-147-2.73.el6_8.2.x86_64.rpm mesa-libGL-17.0.1-6.20170307.el7.i686.rpm mesa-libglapi-17.0.1-6.20170307.el7.i686.rpm 'vivaldi-stable-1.12.955.48-1.x86_64(1).rpm' vivaldi-stable-1.12.955.48-1.x86_64.rpm xflux xflux64.tgz xorg-x11-server-1.17.2-22.el7.src.rpm xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.17.4-16.el6.centos.i686.rpm xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.19.3-11.el7.x86_64.rpm rpmfusion-free-updates: mirrors.lug.mtu.edu amdgpu-pro-17.30-458935 amdgpu-pro-17.30-458935.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261 amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.40-501128.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.50-511655 amdgpu-pro-17.50-511655.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-preinstall.sh cert-forensics-tools-release-el7.rpm eclipse-java-photon-M4-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz expat-2.1.0-10.el7_3.i686.rpm fluxgui 'IBM US Relocation Questionaire _TAC.doc' lib64udev0-182-5-mdv2012.0.x86_64.rpm libdrm-2.4.74-1.el7.i686.rpm libpciaccess-0.13.4-3.el7_3.i686.rpm libselinux-2.5-11.el7.i686.rpm libsepol-2.5-6.el7.x86_64.rpm libudev-147-2.73.el6_8.2.x86_64.rpm mesa-libGL-17.0.1-6.20170307.el7.i686.rpm mesa-libglapi-17.0.1-6.20170307.el7.i686.rpm 'vivaldi-stable-1.12.955.48-1.x86_64(1).rpm' vivaldi-stable-1.12.955.48-1.x86_64.rpm xflux xflux64.tgz xorg-x11-server-1.17.2-22.el7.src.rpm xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.17.4-16.el6.centos.i686.rpm xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.19.3-11.el7.x86_64.rpm ulyaoth: repos.ulyaoth.io amdgpu-pro-17.30-458935 amdgpu-pro-17.30-458935.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261 amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.40-501128.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.50-511655 amdgpu-pro-17.50-511655.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-preinstall.sh cert-forensics-tools-release-el7.rpm eclipse-java-photon-M4-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz expat-2.1.0-10.el7_3.i686.rpm fluxgui 'IBM US Relocation Questionaire _TAC.doc' lib64udev0-182-5-mdv2012.0.x86_64.rpm libdrm-2.4.74-1.el7.i686.rpm libpciaccess-0.13.4-3.el7_3.i686.rpm libselinux-2.5-11.el7.i686.rpm libsepol-2.5-6.el7.x86_64.rpm libudev-147-2.73.el6_8.2.x86_64.rpm mesa-libGL-17.0.1-6.20170307.el7.i686.rpm mesa-libglapi-17.0.1-6.20170307.el7.i686.rpm 'vivaldi-stable-1.12.955.48-1.x86_64(1).rpm' vivaldi-stable-1.12.955.48-1.x86_64.rpm xflux xflux64.tgz xorg-x11-server-1.17.2-22.el7.src.rpm xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.17.4-16.el6.centos.i686.rpm xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.19.3-11.el7.x86_64.rpm updates: centos.mirror.lstn.net repo id repo name status '!adobe-linux-x86_64' Adobe Systems Incorporated 3 '!amdgpu-pro-local' AMD amdgpu Pro local repository 60 '!base/7/x86_64' CentOS-7 - Base 9,591 '!epel/x86_64' Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x8 12,184 '!extras/7/x86_64' CentOS-7 - Extras 327 '!forensics/7/x86_64' CERT Forensics Tools Repository 1,439 '!forensics-splunk/7/x86_64' CERT Forensics Tools Repository - Splunk 3 '!nux-dextop/x86_64' Nux.Ro RPMs for general desktop use 2,570 '!rpmfusion-free-updates/x86_64' RPM Fusion for EL 7 - Free - Updates 223 '!ulyaoth/7/x86_64' Ulyaoth Repository 1,312 '!updates/7/x86_64' CentOS-7 - Updates 1,573 '!vivaldi' vivaldi 15 repolist: 29,300
+ [[ -n Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile amdgpu-pro-17.30-458935 amdgpu-pro-17.30-458935.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261 amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.40-501128.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.50-511655 amdgpu-pro-17.50-511655.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-preinstall.sh cert-forensics-tools-release-el7.rpm eclipse-java-photon-M4-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz expat-2.1.0-10.el7_3.i686.rpm fluxgui IBM US Relocation Questionaire _TAC.doc lib64udev0-182-5-mdv2012.0.x86_64.rpm libdrm-2.4.74-1.el7.i686.rpm libpciaccess-0.13.4-3.el7_3.i686.rpm libselinux-2.5-11.el7.i686.rpm libsepol-2.5-6.el7.x86_64.rpm libudev-147-2.73.el6_8.2.x86_64.rpm mesa-libGL-17.0.1-6.20170307.el7.i686.rpm mesa-libglapi-17.0.1-6.20170307.el7.i686.rpm vivaldi-stable-1.12.955.48-1.x86_64(1).rpm vivaldi-stable-1.12.955.48-1.x86_64.rpm xflux xflux64.tgz xorg-x11-server-1.17.2-22.el7.src.rpm xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.17.4-16.el6.centos.i686.rpm xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.19.3-11.el7.x86_64.rpm base: centos.mirror.lstn.net amdgpu-pro-17.30-458935 amdgpu-pro-17.30-458935.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261 amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.40-501128.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.50-511655 amdgpu-pro-17.50-511655.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-preinstall.sh cert-forensics-tools-release-el7.rpm eclipse-java-photon-M4-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz expat-2.1.0-10.el7_3.i686.rpm fluxgui IBM US Relocation Questionaire _TAC.doc lib64udev0-182-5-mdv2012.0.x86_64.rpm libdrm-2.4.74-1.el7.i686.rpm libpciaccess-0.13.4-3.el7_3.i686.rpm libselinux-2.5-11.el7.i686.rpm libsepol-2.5-6.el7.x86_64.rpm libudev-147-2.73.el6_8.2.x86_64.rpm mesa-libGL-17.0.1-6.20170307.el7.i686.rpm mesa-libglapi-17.0.1-6.20170307.el7.i686.rpm vivaldi-stable-1.12.955.48-1.x86_64(1).rpm vivaldi-stable-1.12.955.48-1.x86_64.rpm xflux xflux64.tgz xorg-x11-server-1.17.2-22.el7.src.rpm xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.17.4-16.el6.centos.i686.rpm xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.19.3-11.el7.x86_64.rpm epel: mirror.rnet.missouri.edu amdgpu-pro-17.30-458935 amdgpu-pro-17.30-458935.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261 amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.40-501128.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.50-511655 amdgpu-pro-17.50-511655.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-preinstall.sh cert-forensics-tools-release-el7.rpm eclipse-java-photon-M4-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz expat-2.1.0-10.el7_3.i686.rpm fluxgui IBM US Relocation Questionaire _TAC.doc lib64udev0-182-5-mdv2012.0.x86_64.rpm libdrm-2.4.74-1.el7.i686.rpm libpciaccess-0.13.4-3.el7_3.i686.rpm libselinux-2.5-11.el7.i686.rpm libsepol-2.5-6.el7.x86_64.rpm libudev-147-2.73.el6_8.2.x86_64.rpm mesa-libGL-17.0.1-6.20170307.el7.i686.rpm mesa-libglapi-17.0.1-6.20170307.el7.i686.rpm vivaldi-stable-1.12.955.48-1.x86_64(1).rpm vivaldi-stable-1.12.955.48-1.x86_64.rpm xflux xflux64.tgz xorg-x11-server-1.17.2-22.el7.src.rpm xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.17.4-16.el6.centos.i686.rpm xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.19.3-11.el7.x86_64.rpm extras: centos.mirror.lstn.net amdgpu-pro-17.30-458935 amdgpu-pro-17.30-458935.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261 amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.40-501128.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.50-511655 amdgpu-pro-17.50-511655.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-preinstall.sh cert-forensics-tools-release-el7.rpm eclipse-java-photon-M4-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz expat-2.1.0-10.el7_3.i686.rpm fluxgui IBM US Relocation Questionaire _TAC.doc lib64udev0-182-5-mdv2012.0.x86_64.rpm libdrm-2.4.74-1.el7.i686.rpm libpciaccess-0.13.4-3.el7_3.i686.rpm libselinux-2.5-11.el7.i686.rpm libsepol-2.5-6.el7.x86_64.rpm libudev-147-2.73.el6_8.2.x86_64.rpm mesa-libGL-17.0.1-6.20170307.el7.i686.rpm mesa-libglapi-17.0.1-6.20170307.el7.i686.rpm vivaldi-stable-1.12.955.48-1.x86_64(1).rpm vivaldi-stable-1.12.955.48-1.x86_64.rpm xflux xflux64.tgz xorg-x11-server-1.17.2-22.el7.src.rpm xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.17.4-16.el6.centos.i686.rpm xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.19.3-11.el7.x86_64.rpm nux-dextop: li.nux.ro amdgpu-pro-17.30-458935 amdgpu-pro-17.30-458935.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261 amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.40-501128.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.50-511655 amdgpu-pro-17.50-511655.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-preinstall.sh cert-forensics-tools-release-el7.rpm eclipse-java-photon-M4-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz expat-2.1.0-10.el7_3.i686.rpm fluxgui IBM US Relocation Questionaire _TAC.doc lib64udev0-182-5-mdv2012.0.x86_64.rpm libdrm-2.4.74-1.el7.i686.rpm libpciaccess-0.13.4-3.el7_3.i686.rpm libselinux-2.5-11.el7.i686.rpm libsepol-2.5-6.el7.x86_64.rpm libudev-147-2.73.el6_8.2.x86_64.rpm mesa-libGL-17.0.1-6.20170307.el7.i686.rpm mesa-libglapi-17.0.1-6.20170307.el7.i686.rpm vivaldi-stable-1.12.955.48-1.x86_64(1).rpm vivaldi-stable-1.12.955.48-1.x86_64.rpm xflux xflux64.tgz xorg-x11-server-1.17.2-22.el7.src.rpm xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.17.4-16.el6.centos.i686.rpm xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.19.3-11.el7.x86_64.rpm rpmfusion-free-updates: mirrors.lug.mtu.edu amdgpu-pro-17.30-458935 amdgpu-pro-17.30-458935.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261 amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.40-501128.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.50-511655 amdgpu-pro-17.50-511655.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-preinstall.sh cert-forensics-tools-release-el7.rpm eclipse-java-photon-M4-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz expat-2.1.0-10.el7_3.i686.rpm fluxgui IBM US Relocation Questionaire _TAC.doc lib64udev0-182-5-mdv2012.0.x86_64.rpm libdrm-2.4.74-1.el7.i686.rpm libpciaccess-0.13.4-3.el7_3.i686.rpm libselinux-2.5-11.el7.i686.rpm libsepol-2.5-6.el7.x86_64.rpm libudev-147-2.73.el6_8.2.x86_64.rpm mesa-libGL-17.0.1-6.20170307.el7.i686.rpm mesa-libglapi-17.0.1-6.20170307.el7.i686.rpm vivaldi-stable-1.12.955.48-1.x86_64(1).rpm vivaldi-stable-1.12.955.48-1.x86_64.rpm xflux xflux64.tgz xorg-x11-server-1.17.2-22.el7.src.rpm xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.17.4-16.el6.centos.i686.rpm xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.19.3-11.el7.x86_64.rpm ulyaoth: repos.ulyaoth.io amdgpu-pro-17.30-458935 amdgpu-pro-17.30-458935.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261 amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.40-501128.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.50-511655 amdgpu-pro-17.50-511655.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-preinstall.sh cert-forensics-tools-release-el7.rpm eclipse-java-photon-M4-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz expat-2.1.0-10.el7_3.i686.rpm fluxgui IBM US Relocation Questionaire _TAC.doc lib64udev0-182-5-mdv2012.0.x86_64.rpm libdrm-2.4.74-1.el7.i686.rpm libpciaccess-0.13.4-3.el7_3.i686.rpm libselinux-2.5-11.el7.i686.rpm libsepol-2.5-6.el7.x86_64.rpm libudev-147-2.73.el6_8.2.x86_64.rpm mesa-libGL-17.0.1-6.20170307.el7.i686.rpm mesa-libglapi-17.0.1-6.20170307.el7.i686.rpm vivaldi-stable-1.12.955.48-1.x86_64(1).rpm vivaldi-stable-1.12.955.48-1.x86_64.rpm xflux xflux64.tgz xorg-x11-server-1.17.2-22.el7.src.rpm xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.17.4-16.el6.centos.i686.rpm xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.19.3-11.el7.x86_64.rpm updates: centos.mirror.lstn.net repo id repo name status !adobe-linux-x86_64 Adobe Systems Incorporated 3 !amdgpu-pro-local AMD amdgpu Pro local repository 60 !base/7/x86_64 CentOS-7 - Base 9,591 !epel/x86_64 Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x8 12,184 !extras/7/x86_64 CentOS-7 - Extras 327 !forensics/7/x86_64 CERT Forensics Tools Repository 1,439 !forensics-splunk/7/x86_64 CERT Forensics Tools Repository - Splunk 3 !nux-dextop/x86_64 Nux.Ro RPMs for general desktop use 2,570 !rpmfusion-free-updates/x86_64 RPM Fusion for EL 7 - Free - Updates 223 !ulyaoth/7/x86_64 Ulyaoth Repository 1,312 !updates/7/x86_64 CentOS-7 - Updates 1,573 !vivaldi vivaldi 15 repolist: 29,300 ]]
+ echo -e 'Something went wrong and the install media repository was not set up successfully.\nTry running the script with root priviledges. '
Something went wrong and the install media repository was not set up successfully.
Try running the script with root priviledges. 
++ grep -v epel
++ echo Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile amdgpu-pro-17.30-458935 amdgpu-pro-17.30-458935.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261 amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.40-501128.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.50-511655 amdgpu-pro-17.50-511655.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-preinstall.sh cert-forensics-tools-release-el7.rpm eclipse-java-photon-M4-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz expat-2.1.0-10.el7_3.i686.rpm fluxgui 'IBM US Relocation Questionaire _TAC.doc' lib64udev0-182-5-mdv2012.0.x86_64.rpm libdrm-2.4.74-1.el7.i686.rpm libpciaccess-0.13.4-3.el7_3.i686.rpm libselinux-2.5-11.el7.i686.rpm libsepol-2.5-6.el7.x86_64.rpm libudev-147-2.73.el6_8.2.x86_64.rpm mesa-libGL-17.0.1-6.20170307.el7.i686.rpm mesa-libglapi-17.0.1-6.20170307.el7.i686.rpm 'vivaldi-stable-1.12.955.48-1.x86_64(1).rpm' vivaldi-stable-1.12.955.48-1.x86_64.rpm xflux xflux64.tgz xorg-x11-server-1.17.2-22.el7.src.rpm xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.17.4-16.el6.centos.i686.rpm xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.19.3-11.el7.x86_64.rpm base: centos.mirror.lstn.net amdgpu-pro-17.30-458935 amdgpu-pro-17.30-458935.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261 amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.40-501128.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.50-511655 amdgpu-pro-17.50-511655.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-preinstall.sh cert-forensics-tools-release-el7.rpm eclipse-java-photon-M4-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz expat-2.1.0-10.el7_3.i686.rpm fluxgui 'IBM US Relocation Questionaire _TAC.doc' lib64udev0-182-5-mdv2012.0.x86_64.rpm libdrm-2.4.74-1.el7.i686.rpm libpciaccess-0.13.4-3.el7_3.i686.rpm libselinux-2.5-11.el7.i686.rpm libsepol-2.5-6.el7.x86_64.rpm libudev-147-2.73.el6_8.2.x86_64.rpm mesa-libGL-17.0.1-6.20170307.el7.i686.rpm mesa-libglapi-17.0.1-6.20170307.el7.i686.rpm 'vivaldi-stable-1.12.955.48-1.x86_64(1).rpm' vivaldi-stable-1.12.955.48-1.x86_64.rpm xflux xflux64.tgz xorg-x11-server-1.17.2-22.el7.src.rpm xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.17.4-16.el6.centos.i686.rpm xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.19.3-11.el7.x86_64.rpm epel: mirror.rnet.missouri.edu amdgpu-pro-17.30-458935 amdgpu-pro-17.30-458935.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261 amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.40-501128.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.50-511655 amdgpu-pro-17.50-511655.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-preinstall.sh cert-forensics-tools-release-el7.rpm eclipse-java-photon-M4-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz expat-2.1.0-10.el7_3.i686.rpm fluxgui 'IBM US Relocation Questionaire _TAC.doc' lib64udev0-182-5-mdv2012.0.x86_64.rpm libdrm-2.4.74-1.el7.i686.rpm libpciaccess-0.13.4-3.el7_3.i686.rpm libselinux-2.5-11.el7.i686.rpm libsepol-2.5-6.el7.x86_64.rpm libudev-147-2.73.el6_8.2.x86_64.rpm mesa-libGL-17.0.1-6.20170307.el7.i686.rpm mesa-libglapi-17.0.1-6.20170307.el7.i686.rpm 'vivaldi-stable-1.12.955.48-1.x86_64(1).rpm' vivaldi-stable-1.12.955.48-1.x86_64.rpm xflux xflux64.tgz xorg-x11-server-1.17.2-22.el7.src.rpm xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.17.4-16.el6.centos.i686.rpm xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.19.3-11.el7.x86_64.rpm extras: centos.mirror.lstn.net amdgpu-pro-17.30-458935 amdgpu-pro-17.30-458935.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261 amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.40-501128.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.50-511655 amdgpu-pro-17.50-511655.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-preinstall.sh cert-forensics-tools-release-el7.rpm eclipse-java-photon-M4-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz expat-2.1.0-10.el7_3.i686.rpm fluxgui 'IBM US Relocation Questionaire _TAC.doc' lib64udev0-182-5-mdv2012.0.x86_64.rpm libdrm-2.4.74-1.el7.i686.rpm libpciaccess-0.13.4-3.el7_3.i686.rpm libselinux-2.5-11.el7.i686.rpm libsepol-2.5-6.el7.x86_64.rpm libudev-147-2.73.el6_8.2.x86_64.rpm mesa-libGL-17.0.1-6.20170307.el7.i686.rpm mesa-libglapi-17.0.1-6.20170307.el7.i686.rpm 'vivaldi-stable-1.12.955.48-1.x86_64(1).rpm' vivaldi-stable-1.12.955.48-1.x86_64.rpm xflux xflux64.tgz xorg-x11-server-1.17.2-22.el7.src.rpm xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.17.4-16.el6.centos.i686.rpm xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.19.3-11.el7.x86_64.rpm nux-dextop: li.nux.ro amdgpu-pro-17.30-458935 amdgpu-pro-17.30-458935.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261 amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.40-501128.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.50-511655 amdgpu-pro-17.50-511655.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-preinstall.sh cert-forensics-tools-release-el7.rpm eclipse-java-photon-M4-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz expat-2.1.0-10.el7_3.i686.rpm fluxgui 'IBM US Relocation Questionaire _TAC.doc' lib64udev0-182-5-mdv2012.0.x86_64.rpm libdrm-2.4.74-1.el7.i686.rpm libpciaccess-0.13.4-3.el7_3.i686.rpm libselinux-2.5-11.el7.i686.rpm libsepol-2.5-6.el7.x86_64.rpm libudev-147-2.73.el6_8.2.x86_64.rpm mesa-libGL-17.0.1-6.20170307.el7.i686.rpm mesa-libglapi-17.0.1-6.20170307.el7.i686.rpm 'vivaldi-stable-1.12.955.48-1.x86_64(1).rpm' vivaldi-stable-1.12.955.48-1.x86_64.rpm xflux xflux64.tgz xorg-x11-server-1.17.2-22.el7.src.rpm xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.17.4-16.el6.centos.i686.rpm xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.19.3-11.el7.x86_64.rpm rpmfusion-free-updates: mirrors.lug.mtu.edu amdgpu-pro-17.30-458935 amdgpu-pro-17.30-458935.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261 amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.40-501128.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.50-511655 amdgpu-pro-17.50-511655.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-preinstall.sh cert-forensics-tools-release-el7.rpm eclipse-java-photon-M4-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz expat-2.1.0-10.el7_3.i686.rpm fluxgui 'IBM US Relocation Questionaire _TAC.doc' lib64udev0-182-5-mdv2012.0.x86_64.rpm libdrm-2.4.74-1.el7.i686.rpm libpciaccess-0.13.4-3.el7_3.i686.rpm libselinux-2.5-11.el7.i686.rpm libsepol-2.5-6.el7.x86_64.rpm libudev-147-2.73.el6_8.2.x86_64.rpm mesa-libGL-17.0.1-6.20170307.el7.i686.rpm mesa-libglapi-17.0.1-6.20170307.el7.i686.rpm 'vivaldi-stable-1.12.955.48-1.x86_64(1).rpm' vivaldi-stable-1.12.955.48-1.x86_64.rpm xflux xflux64.tgz xorg-x11-server-1.17.2-22.el7.src.rpm xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.17.4-16.el6.centos.i686.rpm xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.19.3-11.el7.x86_64.rpm ulyaoth: repos.ulyaoth.io amdgpu-pro-17.30-458935 amdgpu-pro-17.30-458935.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261 amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.40-501128.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-17.50-511655 amdgpu-pro-17.50-511655.tar.xz amdgpu-pro-preinstall.sh cert-forensics-tools-release-el7.rpm eclipse-java-photon-M4-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz expat-2.1.0-10.el7_3.i686.rpm fluxgui 'IBM US Relocation Questionaire _TAC.doc' lib64udev0-182-5-mdv2012.0.x86_64.rpm libdrm-2.4.74-1.el7.i686.rpm libpciaccess-0.13.4-3.el7_3.i686.rpm libselinux-2.5-11.el7.i686.rpm libsepol-2.5-6.el7.x86_64.rpm libudev-147-2.73.el6_8.2.x86_64.rpm mesa-libGL-17.0.1-6.20170307.el7.i686.rpm mesa-libglapi-17.0.1-6.20170307.el7.i686.rpm 'vivaldi-stable-1.12.955.48-1.x86_64(1).rpm' vivaldi-stable-1.12.955.48-1.x86_64.rpm xflux xflux64.tgz xorg-x11-server-1.17.2-22.el7.src.rpm xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.17.4-16.el6.centos.i686.rpm xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.19.3-11.el7.x86_64.rpm updates: centos.mirror.lstn.net repo id repo name status '!adobe-linux-x86_64' Adobe Systems Incorporated 3 '!amdgpu-pro-local' AMD amdgpu Pro local repository 60 '!base/7/x86_64' CentOS-7 - Base 9,591 '!epel/x86_64' Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x8 12,184 '!extras/7/x86_64' CentOS-7 - Extras 327 '!forensics/7/x86_64' CERT Forensics Tools Repository 1,439 '!forensics-splunk/7/x86_64' CERT Forensics Tools Repository - Splunk 3 '!nux-dextop/x86_64' Nux.Ro RPMs for general desktop use 2,570 '!rpmfusion-free-updates/x86_64' RPM Fusion for EL 7 - Free - Updates 223 '!ulyaoth/7/x86_64' Ulyaoth Repository 1,312 '!updates/7/x86_64' CentOS-7 - Updates 1,573 '!vivaldi' vivaldi 15 repolist: 29,300
+ [[ -n '' ]]
+ echo -e 'The required repositories have been set up.\nPlease run amdgpu-pro-install to install the amdgpu-pro driver.'
The required repositories have been set up.
Please run amdgpu-pro-install to install the amdgpu-pro driver.
+ echo ''
```

Comment: Can you explain "I have followed the AMD guide"?

Comment: Yeah I followed this guide, swapping out values for the most up to date drivers [link](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/How-To-Install-Uninstall-AMDGPU-PRO-driver-on-a-CentOS-Based-System.aspx)

Comment: Ok, can you send the output of: "rpm -qa | grep amdgpu-pro"?

Comment: Yeah, it output nothing

Comment: Ok, and at which step do you have this error?

Comment: When I follow the guide and run the `./amdgpu-pro-install -y` command it fails

Answer (score 1):

When I search the internet for `xserver-abi(videodrv-19)` I find [this](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=xserver-abi%28videodrv-19%29&submit=Search+...&system=&arch=).

That is: the package `xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.17.4-16.el6` provides the interface that the version of `glamor-amdgpu` that you are installing needs. So you'd have to install `xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.17.4-16.el6` (or a similar package that provides the `xserver-abi(videodrv-19)` interface) first in order to satisfy the needs/dependencies of the version of `glamor-amdgpu` that you are installing.

Now you can certainly do that, but you are risking that you'll completely break your system. What you need is a version of `glamor-amdgpu` that matches (or more precisely which is compiled against) the version of the X server that is installed on your system.

As shown in the link above, if you do a `yum info xorg-x11-server-Xorg` then you should be able to find out which version you have. Then you'll need to find the correct `glamor-amdgpu` package.

Just from looking at the numbers I guess the `19` in `1.19` represents the `videodrv` interface version, but I could be mistaken.

Comment: I have 1.19.3 and it provides `xserver-abi(videodrv-23)`, so I would say that yes, it's a coincidence.

Comment: Okay, I also have 1.19.3, but how should I go about finding the version of glamor-amdgpu and how would I change my install?

Comment: did you `sudo sh amdgpu-pro-preinstall.sh --check`? What did it say? And what about the follow up `sudo sh amdgpu-pro-preinstall.sh`?

Comment: Preinstall --check: The required repositories have been set up. No changes were made. When I run it without the check it gives me an error, saying that I need to run the script with root privileges even when I sign in as root.

Comment: what is "sign in as root"? You mean log in? And when you do `sudo sh amdgpu-pro-preinstall.sh` it says you should run it as root? What does `sudo id` return?

Comment: I used su to switch to the root account. It says that I should try running it with root privileges. Sudo id returns: `uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023`

Comment: try to [disable selinux](http://idroot.net/tutorials/how-to-disable-selinux-on-centos-7/) and rerun the command. In case that'd work, you may want to re-enable selinux afterwards.

Comment: I have done that and received the same error

Comment: what does `sudo id` say then?

Comment: It says, `uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)`

Comment: you can try to debug/trace that script. Do a `sudo sh -x amdgpu-pro-preinstall.sh` (note the `-x`) to see, what the script is doing and where it's failing. (I'm not sure where `-x` is a switch supported by all shells, possibly you'll need to do a `sudo bash -x amdgpu-pro-preinstall.sh`).

Comment: So, that worked. However, I'm not sure what I'm looking for in this block of text.

Comment: The pre-installer says that "you should try running it with root privileges". That means that the pre-installer tries to do something, tests something, and that fails and so it assumes that you are not running it as root. You now need to find out that that "something" that it tries to do or test it. You should be able to find it in that "block of text". Can you add that "block of text" to the question maybe?

Comment: I'll add it right now.

Comment: Thanks for your help Tomáš, however, I am leaving this job for 8 months and won't have access to this computer. Hopefully when I return the problem is rectified.